# Return WebElement just when visible

Tags: java, selenium

Im getting a list of `WebElement` in which only one element is visible. Im using this method to return that element:

```
public WebElement getVisibleElement(List<WebElement> elements){
    for(WebElement element : elements){
        if(element.isDisplayed())
            return element;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Here's the xpath im using and the elements it returns.

[image]

Comment: Why are you getting list of all elements and iterate to find visible element instead of getting only visible element??

Comment: Im using an xpath to get the elements. It returns multiple elements with the same style and attributes but only one is displayed.

Comment: Then you need to use unique locator to find only single visible element by passing index in locator.. could you share elements HTML as well that's why we can provide you better solution...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i added the xpath im using and the elements returned.

Comment: Please share HTML and xpath here instead of screen shot and let me know which one you want from list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use here `findElement` instead of `findElements` by using unique `xpath` locator with index as below :-

```
//Assuming first element from list is visible 
String indexOfVisbleElement = "1";
String xpath = "(.//table//td[@class = 'button' and b = 'Refresh'])[" +indexOfVisbleElement+ "]";

//Now find only visible element 
WebElement visibleEl = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```

Comment: That may be a good way of doing it, but i would like the method to be reusable and im not sure if the index can change.

Comment: Ok if you are not sure abou index.. could you tell me what version of Java are you using??

Comment: Im using Java 7 and jdk 1.7.0

Comment: Then you method to find visible element from the list looks ok..:)